# Printing the argument in powershell

Tags: powershell, syntax

May I know, why the string argument is not printed in the following powershell script?

```
function Get-Name ( [string] $Username ) {
    echo "user : $Username"
}


PS C:\> .\Get-Name.ps1 -username "test"
PS C:\>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that you define a *function*, not a callable script. [*grin*] this will work ...

```
Param ([string] $Username)

echo "user : $Username"
```

---

here's an example of calling the above ...

```
. .\Func_Get-Name.ps1 -username 'tutu'
```

output ...

```
user : tutu
```

Comment: Well, I want to define a function because I want to call that from command line

Comment: If I write `Param([string]$Username) { echo "user : $Username"}` and then run `.\Get-Name.ps1 -Username "test"`, I will see `echo "user :$Username" in the output`.  In other words, it just prints the line itself.

Comment: @mahmood - you cannot run a function inside a file unless you provide some way to let the function know [1] that it is being called & [2] what you are sending to it. ///// i've added a sample call & the output from it to the answer post.

Comment: @mahmood: Note how Lee's code does _not_ have enclosing `{ ... }` around the `echo` command - with the latter, you're defining a _script block_ inside the script, which is implicitly output, and a script block prints as its _literal contents_.

Answer (score 7):

The script file `Get-Name.ps1` only *defines* the function `Get-Name`, it doesn't execute it.

Use the dot-source operator (`.`) to have it define the function in the calling scope, and then you can execute the function itself:

```
PS C:\> . .\Get-Name.ps1
PS C:\> Get-Name -Username test
user : test
```

Alternatively, remove the `function Get-Name {` and `}` part of the script [as pointed out by Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53144625/712649), at which point the script file becomes a parameterized function in itself and you can then do:

```
PS C:\> .\Get-Name.ps1 -Username test
user : test
```

Please see the [`about_Scripts` help file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts), especially the section about [script scope and dot sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing)